# Pass one of three stripe price IDs to server for creating user session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I have three different product IDs for my subscription app but can't figure out how to have the server redirect to the proper customer session based on which price ID is passed from the client side.

The three price ids work (I've checked each individually) and are coming from my .env file -- they're saved as below:

```
  const { webUrl, stripeSecret, stripeWebhookSecret, basicPriceId, scaledPriceId } = require('../production');
```

**Controller function** - help needed under the `line_items` array for `price`

```
module.exports.createCheckoutSession = async (req, res) => {
    const { currency } = req.body;

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (!(req.user.stripe_customer && req.user.stripe_customer[currency])) {
            const new_stripe_customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.user.email,
                name: req.user.username,
                metadata: {
                    user_id: req.user._id.toString(),
                },
            });

            let update = {};
            update[`stripe_customer.${currency}`] = new_stripe_customer.id;
            update['customer_name'] = new_stripe_customer.name;
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, update);

            if (!req.user.stripe_customer) {
                req.user.stripe_customer = {};
                req.user.stripe_customer[currency] = new_stripe_customer.id;
            } else {
                req.user.stripe_customer[currency] = new_stripe_customer.id;
            }
            const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
            user.stripeId = new_stripe_customer.id;
            await user.save();
        }
        try {
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                mode: "subscription",
                customer: req.user.stripe_customer[currency],
                line_items: [
                    {
                    
                        // where I need help

                        price: { basicPriceId, scaledPriceId, enterprisePriceId },
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                ],

            success_url: `${webUrl}/users/${req.user._id}/activations/?session_id=    {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
                cancel_url: `${webUrl}/canceled.html`,

            });
            return res.redirect(303, session.url);

        } catch (e) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({
                error: {
                    message: e.message,
                }
            });
        }
    }
    req.flash('error', "You must login before changing billing");
    res.render('/login');
}
```

With the three price id variables listed in the price row, I receive `{"error":{"message":"enterprisePriceId is not defined"}}`.

However, the ids are properly being passed from client to server so if I switch the row from all three variables listed to only one of the variables listed it works just fine:

**Doesn't work**

- `price: { basicPriceId, scaledPriceId, enterprisePriceId },`

**Works**

- `price: basicPriceId,`

How do I structure the controller code so the user can choose between the three different prices and be redirected to the proper payment checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

You should check which one is present *before* making the Checkout Session call, and pass the proper value in. The Checkout Session Creation API expects a valid value.

Comment: Thanks @orakaro - how would I do that?

Comment: Right now my `req.body` is coming through as `{ scaledPriceId: 'scaledPriceId' }`